# Как отменить голос за удаление?

Tags: поддержка, удаление-ответов

Собственно, проголосовал за удаление [ответа](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/690273/178988), потом понял, что я неправильно понял вопрос. А как отменить голос?

Comment: никак, но можешь попробовать тревогнуть модераторам с кастомной причиной

Comment: @Grundy, а смысл?

Comment: Больше репы - больше проблем. Не всё можно отменить. Например, в очереди проверок тоже нельзя переголосовать, если выполнил мисклик.

Comment: @alexolut, но там можно зайти в сам вопрос и поменять) Не результат проверки конечно, но всё же.

Comment: @Qwertiy и кто-то потеряет +2 из-за этого. А еще может и в бан попасть из-за частых отклонений правок.

Comment: @alexolut, ты про очередь правок что ли?

Comment: @Qwertiy хотя бы.

Comment: Почти четыре года назад захотели такое: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/193061/339911

Comment: @Qwertiy Как много я пропустил! Вы подались в удалистов, миновав закрывашек?